# Give all units in region

Tags: starcraft-2

In the map editor, is there a trigger to give all units within a region to another player? "Change Ownership" only applies to a single unit.

Comment: Most likely then, you'll simply have to loop over each unit in the region and apply the change ownership function each time.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You can use `PickEachUnitInGroup` + `UnitSetOwner`.

[image]

[image]